# How to justified multiline text covered tspan tags in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, text-alignment

Do you know how to justified multiline text covered tspan tags in d3.js?
I have a description block with text from .json file:

Here's what I've tried. I tried to set `text-anchor` to `justify`,
because the `<tspan>` element doesn't have `text-align`. So `d3js` is generating this code.

```js
let infoBox = d3.select("#info-box")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("id", "info-box-text")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "info-box")
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 30)
  .attr("transform", "translate(125)"); //text-anchor center
```

```css
.info-box text {
  /*description style*/
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Open Sans, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, Calibri, sans-serif;
  fill: #7c7c7c;
}

.info-box text tspan {
  padding: 20px;
}

#info-box svg {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 600px;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="info-box-text">
          <g class="info-box">
            <text x="0" y="30" transform="translate(125)">
              <tspan x="0" y="30" dy="0em">Lorem ipsum</tspan>
              <tspan x="0" y="30" dy="1.1em">dolor sit amet, consectetur</tspan>
              <tspan x="0" y="30" dy="2.2em">adipiscing elit</tspan>                    
           </text>
         </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: That text is justified. What's exactly the problem?

Comment: SVG is not intended for text layout, that's what HTML is for. There's no justification or even line wrapping in SVG. I would suggest overlaying a `div` outside the SVG and applying `text-align: justify` to that.

Comment: Hello Gerardo. Now it works as text-align: center, but it was realised through tspan text-anchor